# Lebesgue measure and compact set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A \subset\mathbb R^d$ be a Lebesgue measurable set and bounded. Show that

$$m(A) = \sup\{m(K) : K \subset A\text{ and }K\text{ compact} \} \in [0,\infty].$$

answer :
I know that for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exist an open set $O$ s.t

$K\subset A\subset O$ and $m(O\setminus K)<\epsilon$ ,
but I dont know how I can use from this inquality?

Comment: The answer to this question heavily depends on the theory that you developed to construct the Lebesgue integral. In some cases that formula is taken as the definition of measure. My standard reference for the topic is http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-88-7642-386-4, which has the proof of that result (frequently described as the property of "inner regularity" of the Lebesgue measure).

Comment: By the way, note that if you are in a compact ambient space the property of inner regularity and the property of outer regularity (the one about open sets, that you say you know) are completely symmetrical: in you have one, the other is an easy corollary (by passing to complement sets).

Answer (score 1):

With your last edit, the answer becomes pretty easy.

By definition of supremum, what you want to prove is that for every $\varepsilon$ there is $K \subset A$ compact such that $m(K) \geq m(A) - \varepsilon$. But such $K$ is easily given by the fact that you know, which is more correctly stated as: for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there are two sets, $O$ open and $K$ compact, such that $K \subset A \subset O$ and $m(O \setminus K) \leq \varepsilon$. Of course this implies *a fortiori* that $m(A \setminus K) \leq \varepsilon$, so $m(K) \geq M(A) - \epsilon$. This concludes the proof.